Chat Event (19/05): May Madness
We've got a pulse!
I'm really (really) happy to say our spring cleaning efforts seem to be having a positive impact on the community, both in terms of our measurable performance and in the actual communal sense. To everyone who's been pitching in, thank you so much. We are making real inroads in both the total amount of unanswered questions and our %Answered ratio, several posts have reached 10 score in less than a week, and the amount of users idling and participating in the Axon Terminal has skyrocketed.
As the original post suggested, we'll have a 45-60 minute discussion to cover spring cleaning-related business, plus any topics you'd like to bring up. I've thrown long-term site strategy in the hat, but please feel free to suggest topics via comments or answers. I will try to keep us more strictly on-topic this time. Based on the previous event, we will most likely not have time to discuss ad-hoc topics, so get your suggestion in!
Time and place
Currently scheduled to take place on 16:00 UTC, Tuesday, May 19th in the Axon Terminal.
This is based on previous very limited information about schedules, and my perception of Tuesday as our strongest weekday in terms of activity. Therefore, please read below!
Our community seems to be spread mainly over EST, UTC, CET and Australian time zones. This makes it very difficult to coordinate in itself, but the extremely limited information I have available makes it essentially pure guesswork on my part. Stack Exchange does many things well, but making it easy to communicate within a community is not one of them. There are a number of people whose schedules I would very much like to accommodate here, but I fear I would inadvertently leave important people out if I named names.
If you are currently participating on the site (i.e., you have recently voted, answered, asked or moderated), or you are a formerly active participant, I would like to know how I can make it as convenient as possible for you to join this and future discussions. We are a small enough community to make this work, but not without some communication. Please leave a comment or contact me in the chat!
If anyone has a good general solution, please post it.
Topics

Spring Cleaning 2015.
Long-term site strategy.
New Close reason ― Steven Jeuris.
[This space for rent.]

Related posts
Steven's collection of audience- and scope-related posts, Chat event: Introductions and Spring Cleaning 2015, Regularly scheduled chat event.

Decision on the new close reason?
